# Add a new code style on PhpStorm

Tags: coding-style, phpstorm

I have started using Semantic UI and I noticed that when I want to customize my css, I need to make `.variables` and `.overrides` files. Their syntax is just like `.less` syntax, but they're treated differently by their types.

What I want now, is when I open a `.variables` or a `.overrides` files, PhpStorm will treat it as a `less` code style. Is it possible to achieve it?

If there's an option to do per Project, it'll be perfect.

Comment: So .. you want a file named `.variables` and `.overrides` (that's the exact names) to be treated as if they are `*.less`? If so -- `Settings/Preferences | Editor | File Types` and add appropriate patterns to "Less" file type. P.S. It's an IDE-wide setting .. but considering rather uniqueness of the file names it should not be an issue (it's pretty unlikely that the same files will have to have different format in other projects).

Comment: @LazyOne TBH I already found this solution when I read their doc, but I forgot to answer my question. Anyways, I think you should post it as an answer.